# Public super group in Telegram

Tags: telegram

In the Telegram website and blog says: we can create a **public super group** that have a **public link** such as a channels.

But I can not create such group and I do not see any option for it.
Only private super group can be created.

Please guide me.

**Update:**

This question is very important for **Iranian** developers, because they use Telegram's supergroups for programming goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that **I live in Iran**, Telegram has imposed this restriction on Iran for some reasons, and therefore, Iranians and those inside Iran cannot create public supergroups or join them.

But:
**Pavel Durov**, *the manager of the telegram*, announced that this restriction will be lifted in **October 2017** and Iranians can also create and join public supergroups.

Answer (score 0):

Only supergroups can be public, not groups. So a group has to be created, then it has to be upgraded to supergroup (only the creatore can) and then you can do it public just personalizing the link.

If you are interested in doing all of this with code, you can't use bot api (they do not allow this), but you have to use mtproto api

Comment: I'm fully aware of this. But I do not know how to make a public link to the supergroup. Please tell me how to do it step by step. I did not see this option in the telegram!